# I have a trigger and I am freezing at working with more than one record on Custom object

Tags: trigger, bulk

My task is I need to count number of times a record has been edited using Edit button after record has been created. For this I created a field called **`Edit_Counting__c`** (Number Type) and also created one workflow on **`MapTesting__c`** to get the count that record has been edited using **`ISCHANGED`** (Field Type).

Later I created one more field called **`Counting__c`** and I created this trigger, assigned **`Edit_counting__c`** with **`Counting__c`** (`maap.Counting__c = maap.Edit_Counting__c+1`).

I am getting my output by using **`Counting__c`** value, but its working for only one record when I click edit button for one record respectively. When I am trying to update more than one record using developer console, the **`Counting__c`** value does not effect to all the modified records.

I do not know where I have done mistake. I also post my code below. Please check it and please could anyone help in this?

Thanks in advance

KS Kumaar

```
trigger MapTesting_Editable on MapTesting__c(after update) {
    List<MapTesting__c> mmp = new List<MapTesting__c>();
    List<MapTesting__c> mm = [select id, Edit_Counting__c, Counting__c from MapTesting__c where Id IN: Trigger.OldMap.keySet()];
    if (RecusrssionTrigger.flag) {
        for (MapTesting__c maap: mm) {
            RecusrssionTrigger.flag = false;
            maap.Counting__c = maap.Edit_Counting__c + 1;
            mmp.add(maap);
        }
        update mmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: May i know why you have go for after update?? why not before update?/

Comment: The workflow will execute on all DML events - including Data Loader and hence will not count the # of edit button save actions.  Furthermore, if using inline editing, there can be multiple save events without ever clicking Edit.  Unclear of your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Think you can avoid apex all together and just use workflow rule that always fires on upon insert and edit.  Then create a field update that sets the  integer field to  the current value + 1.

Comment: Sorry for the late Reply.
Thanks for you response
@Benjamin Pirih, I can obey with your answer. But I want to do it using Trigger concept.. Please help me in this........!

Comment: First rule of Salesforce Club.. you do not write code if you don't have to.. Second rule of Salesforce Club.. you DO NOT write code if you don't have to..